# How do you find out what instance it is when described in an error? (swift)

Tags: swift

I've been trying to figure out this bug for a long while, and i can't figure out  where the error is (I have a debug point literally everywhere in my code), and I was wondering if I could use the error to find out where it is (ie figure out what instance 0x100b15ad0 is)

Fun Error Below:

```
2016-10-21 23:09:56.870436 AppName[1992:639323] -[AppName.ScannerView unhighlight]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100b15ad0
2016-10-21 23:09:56.871918 AppName[1992:639323] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppName.ScannerView unhighlight]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100b15ad0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1851001c0 0x183b3855c 0x185107278 0x185104278 0x184ffe59c 0x185be7988 0x1850ae8f4 0x1850ae608 0x1850adec4 0x1850abac0 0x184fda048 0x186a5d198 0x18afb3818 0x18afae550 0x100024994 0x183fbc5b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: (not sure how to format the error, should I formate it like code?)

Comment: This is Swift 3 By the Way (if that helps)

Comment: Search for who calls the method `unhighlight`.

Comment: @kennytm thank you so much, I fixed my error! :D